# FMC as ground through the house

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding

Is it acceptable to use FMC as a ground from the outlets to the box? I see in the electrical code it says it can be 50ft for a branch circuit and 6ft for a feeder. I'm just really looking to understand the difference between feeder and branch and if the FMC being longer than 6ft through the walls is acceptable.

Comment: Do you really mean FMC?  Or do you mean MC?   FMC would be a very expensive and unnecessarily laborious way to wire a house and it's hard to imagine why you would use a 50+ foot run of it.  As for MC, can you even buy it without a ground conductor ?  I don't think I've seen that in shops in decades ... though I don't shop in specialty electric stores.

Comment: So this is in a house I'm buying. All of the outlets are just the 2 prong with no ground, but they ran the wire in conduit. I'm trying to figure out if I need to run new wiring or can use the FMC as ground. and yes it's FMC. From what I understand they had it left over from another project and just used it. @jay613

Comment: @jay613 by the way 50ft is an example. I'm just wondering if more than 6ft is fine.

Comment: The savings *.vs.* a roll of green or bare are not huge, on a house, and the grounding is better. If your'e willing to bother to strip it yourself, bare copper from NM/B might be even less, but if you count your time for anything, a roll is worth it.

Comment: You should add more details to the question if you have an unusual existing install and want to know A) if it is allowable and/or can be grandfathered and B) just how safe or not it might be ... should you urgently replace it all?  Include your location, pictures, lengths, what wires were run in the conduit, etc.  More details and more detailed questions will help.  I've seen the experts suggest in other Questions that when replacing 2-prong outlets in boxes with questionable ground paths, ungrounded GFIs are better than poorly grounded three-prong outlets.  You may have options.

Comment: Also if it's properly run FMC maybe you can pull grounds through it?  :)

Comment: A branch circuit is a circut past the final breaker. A feeder is a circuit that "feeds" more breakers. Examples: Regular outlet and lighting circuits are branches. A sub panel is connected to a main panel by a feeder.

Comment: @jay613 Unfortunately I don't have pictures just yet. and pulling a ground through them might be a good option. I don't want to have to tear out any drywall. My main concern is that I have expensive home server equipment and want to make sure I do anything I can to save money but if need be hire a professional.

Comment: @longneck so FMC is allowed to be longer than 6ft like I thought.

Comment: Again ... details IN THE QUESTION will help!  If you have a rack of equipment that relies on good ground for reasons other than human safety, you don't need to rewire your whole house!    There are lots of ways to provide functional ground reference to a single location based on the specific needs ... be explicit!

Comment: @jay613 so I'm looking to have ground for everything in the house because I'm a tech guy and really like to have a lot of computers and devices. My gaming pc is top of the line as well as my girlfriends. I want to make sure it's all protected. obviously safety is a factor but the good grounds are required to keep my thousands of dollars worth of equipment up and running. But again, having it in my whole house would be the ideal in the endgame.

Comment: @ecnerwal They sell THHN in green? News to me :) :) :)  Seriously a big reason to use FMC instead of Romex or PVC is the AFCI rules: FMC lets you put the AFCI *at the first receptacle* ($18) instead of breaker ($40). That's especially important for a MWBC that needs both, because then you can use 2-pole GFCI breaker + AFCI receptacles if your vendor doesn't make 2-pole AFCIs.

Comment: I have a no longer full roll of #10 stranded that says they do, indeed. It cost me less than $100, which might give an idea of how long I've owned it.

Comment: @PaulB -- if you're dealing with actual FMC (as opposed to MC or AC, look for the polypropylene or paper tape/filler in the cables), then fishing a ground wire should be NBD for a reasonably skilled electrician

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 6' is the maximum, with no exceptions

The NEC sets 6' (in 250.118 points 5 thru 7) as the upper bound on *all* flexible metallic conduit types (LFMC, FMC, and FMT), *taken together*, when used as part of an equipment grounding conductor.  So, provided that this is actual flexible metallic conduit and there's enough room to slink a bare ground wire of the appropriate size down it, I would simply do that instead of relying on the FMC as a ground.

Comment: that's a beautiful answer. thank you so much. I'll just fish a ground instead.

Comment: @PaulB if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the appropriate way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to all answers that help you and the check mark next to the one that helps you the _most_.

Comment: @freeman I can't hit the up arrow with less than 15 reputation..